# How to delete order?

Tags: expresso-store

How do I delete an order (expresso store) in the control panel?  I'd like to be able to delete the tests I'm doing.  Even cmd+f "delete" on the pages turns up nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order deletion functionality was removed in Store 2.5 - apparently in error - and will reportedly return in a forthcoming point release.