# Remove Test Orders in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, stripe, orders

How do I remove test orders from an Expresso Store?

EE 2.9.2 / Expresso Store 2.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below is correct for every version but 2.5.0. In 2.5.1 the checkbox is on the left and you can delete entries. The checkboxes were accidentally removed in version 2.5.0.

Answer (score 3):

I asked this question earlier, and it turns out in 2.5 the delete functionality was accidentally removed according to the answer.

[How to delete order?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/31328/how-to-delete-order)

Answer (score -2):

Uhh, from the documentation:

```
Orders can be selected using the checkboxes on the right. The Select Action
drop-down can be used to bulk update the order status, or delete orders. Note
that if the status of multiple orders is updated, they will each be sent any 
email notifications assigned to the new order status.
```

I've never used this addon, and it took me a less than 7 seconds to find the answer. Sorry, I don't mean to be sarcastic, but give the documentation a good look! It can answer many of your questions. This is the page I found your answer on (it has pictures that can probably help):

https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/control_panel_orders.html

Comment: I had given the docs a very good look and had come across the info you linked to. The option you mention is not available in the version I'm using, which is why I included the version number.